# Adding rows to HTML table using powershell

Tags: html, powershell, internet-explorer, appendchild

I am writing an application which uses HTML in IE as GUI. Now I want use a table for the output of data in the browser.
For this I open a local HTML in the browser:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate2($GuiFile)
$ie.Visible = $true
```

and so on. I this HTML file I can read and write input fields. But I want change the HTML, or better the DOM standing behind it.

```
$myTable=$ie.Document.getElementById("ReportsTable")
$myNewRow = $ie.Document.createElement("TR")
$myNewRow.setAttribute("id", "myTr")
$myTable.appendChild($myNewRow)
```

Sounds good, doesn't it? However I get to the last call of "appendChild" an Object, it should adde the Child (TR) to the existing table.

Thx a lot for any advice

Eryk

Comment: You want to use Internet Explorer as an HTML editor, and save your changes to the HTML file?

Comment: Next level xss omega

Comment: No, I want to use the IE as GUI. The application should write its output into a table in the HTML page.